# Can a UITabBar (not UITabBarController) have multiple selections?

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uiswitch

In one of my views I need a control that lets the user multi-pick items on a horizontal, graphical list (tap to select, tap again to deselect...think: locking pushbuttons across the screen).

Rather than laying out a bunch of UISwitch controls side-by-side I want to use something prettier...icons of the elements being chosen.  I thought a custom UITabBar might do the trick.

Is there a way to get the buttons on a UITabBar to lock state in a multi-pick fashion?  So if my user taps the 1st, 2nd, and 4th buttons they stay selected but the 3rd, 5th, and 6th don't?

(If not, I guess I can build something.  Can a standard UISwitch control take on a different look?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there’s nothing in [the `UITabBar` API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that indicates that you can have multiple selections.

As for customizing `UISwitch`—that’s not what you want. As of iOS 7 you [can no longer set a custom “on” or “off” image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISwitch/onImage). You’re better off customizing `UIButton`, which isn’t *quite* as close semantically, but which still provides all of the API you’ll need for your application.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  UIButtons and logic to lock'em it is.  Thanks!